# ASP.NET MVC default path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to figure out how to route my application to a default controller/task/id when none is specified in a request.

Here is my one routing instruction...

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
     controller = "LML",
     action = "TaskLibrary",
     id = 7
     //id = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
   );
```

Using this, if I enter in 'http://mywebsite/', the proper controller/action/id is called.  However, I would like the URL to reflect this.  Rather the URL remains untouched from what I entered.

Using routing, is there a way to affect the URL so that it redisplays synced with the controller/action/id it is showing by default?  Or do I have to create some sort of redirect action?

Comment: please tag with asp.net next time ---- mvc is a generic term, it is not asp specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routing is about mapping a request to an action, not about redirecting.

You could change your default route parameters to default to another action that simply redirects to "LML/TaskLibrary/7"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I am just learning MVC.  So you are suggesting the default route params hit a controller action that simply redirects to a default URL?  Sorry if obvious.  Still learning!

Comment: Keep in mind that default route parameters are used when there's no match on the request. Using your route, the following requests are the same - "/", "/LML", "/LML/TaskLibrary" and "/LML/TaskLibrary/7". It's up to you to decide the best landing page (no parameters so use all defaults) for your site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 4, and often like to see where the change can be made. So, for those who'd like to see the previous answer in code...

In RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "LML", action = "TaskLibrary", id = 7 }
               );
```

The main difference from the original example, is the addition of "defaults:".

I hope this helps someone!